# Cannot Implicityly Convert Type Void To Type System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>

Tags: c#, generics

Trying to return a generic type and am getting the error decribed in the title. 
I am sure I am doing something silly - suggestions appreciated...

```
public static IList<T> GetGroupById<T>(int groupId)
        {

            DashboardGroupType type = (DashboardGroupType)groupId;
            IList<T> result = null;

            var obj = default(T);

            switch (type)
            {
                case DashboardGroupType.Countries:
                    break;
                case DashboardGroupType.Customers:
                    // this returns a list of typ  IEnumerable<Customer>
                    obj = (T) CustomerRepository.GetAllCustomers();
                    break;
                case DashboardGroupType.Facilities:
                    // this returns a list of typ  IEnumerable<Facility>
                    obj = (T) FacilityRepository.GetAllFacilities();
                    break;
                case DashboardGroupType.Heiarchy:
                    break;
                case DashboardGroupType.Lines:
                    break;
                case DashboardGroupType.Regions:
                    // this returns a list of typ  IEnumerable<string>
                    obj = (T) CustomerRepository.GetRegionsHavingCustomers();
                    break;
                case DashboardGroupType.States:
                    // // this returns a list of typ  IEnumerable<Customer>
                    obj = (T) CustomerRepository.GetStatesHavingCustomers();
                    break;
                case DashboardGroupType.Tanks:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            result = result.Add(obj); // ERROR IS THROWN HERE

        }
```

Comment: bad use of Switch-case, since cases that not doing anything need not to be used...

Comment: It is not complete - I need to add the respository pattern for some of these... I am just breaking the incomplete ones for now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/63ywd54z.aspx) method does not return anything. It simply changes the list. That's why you're getting the error. Just remove the assignment:

```
result.Add(obj);
```

Another problem is that you're not initializing result. You will get a NullReferenceException when running the code. You need something like this:

```
IList<T> result = new List<T>();
```

You'll also need to return a value from this function. I'm guessing you want to

```
return result;
```

According to your comments, the methods `CustomerRepository.GetAllCustomers();` and `FacilityRepository.GetAllFacilities();` and the likes return instances of `IEnumerable<Customer>`, or `IEnumerable<Facility>`, or similar. You are casting these to T. This means that all of those types have to be castable to T.

I'm guessing that what you wanted was to take all the items in those collections and add them to the list. If that is the case, you should cast to `IEnumerable<T>` instead, and call the [`AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) method.

Overall, this seems like a very poor design. Depending on what you're trying to achieve, it may be possible to get a better design using inheritance and/or interfaces.

Comment: @Code Sherpa: It's difficult to say more without more details (like what is a dashboard group, and how, where, and what for you will call GetGroupById). Perhaps you can post another question better detailing what your goals are.

Comment: Thanks Martinho, I'll do that now... I appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi Martinho, I have posted background on what I am doing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877757/looking-for-some-general-feedback-regarding-my-server-design-esp-regarding-the-u Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 10):

```
result = result.Add(obj);
```

Add() does not return anything.
remove the "result ="

Comment: A valid point but not the actual cause of the error. +1 for a good point though (and as a welcome to SO).

Comment: Yes, but you should still add `return result;` at the end

Comment: …and initialize `result` somewhere.

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes: wow was that an embarrassing comment on my part. You are totally right and I was totally not thinking about it properly. I'd love to delete the comment but I think I will leave it there so yours still makes sense and a reminder to me to pay attention and *think*.

Answer (score 4):

Your method says it will return IList, but you are not returning anything (hence, returning void). You should be returning result, if I am not mistaken.

**EDIT:**

Actually, upon further review, I realize that the issue is that `result.Add` returns void, and the line

`result = result.Add(obj);` is attempting to assign it to result (which is the `List`). This is why this line is having the error, but also you need to return result and instantiate it before adding anything to it.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you assigning result

`result = result.Add(obj);`

This will work fine, if you use

```
result.Add(obj);
```

and last line to be `return result;`

Answer (score 1):

Two things: You should be returning result at the end, and when declaring result at the start you should be declaring it as new List rather than null.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the return statement.

```
return result;
```